# Does character length attribute be the part of lexer or parser?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lexer

I am building a compiler and have one doubt. In case of STRING, we do not have any idea about the length, but in case of CHARACTER we know that it will be either 3 or 4 symbols including starting and ending single quotes (ex. ‘a’, ‘/t’). So, can we take advantage of this knowledge and flag error in the Lexer if length of input string is more than 4 symbols or this is the work of Parser?

Ex. ‘aaaaaaaaaaa’

Is this a lexical error for character or syntactic error? What could be the optimal location for this check?

Comment: That depends entirely on the intended semantics of the language you are intending to parse. For example, in Python, `'some string'` is (almost) entirely equivalent to `"some string"`. Not so much in C or C++, where the single quotes are used for character literals, including multi-byte character literals, and the double quotes denote a string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, `‘aaaaaaaaaaa’` is neither a lexical nor a syntactic error, although its semantics are implementation-defined:

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g.,
>   'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte
>   execution character, is implementation-defined. (C standard, section 6.4.4.4, paragraph 10.)

It would have been easy to restrict character constants to a single character or escape sequence, but not by counting the display length of the character constant. (For example, `'ab'` (length 4) would be illegal while `'\x2C'` (length 5) is legal, and `'\u00C3'` (length 6) depends on encoding.)

In any case, the frontier between "lexical" and "syntactic" errors is not particularly well-defined, and particularly not for C, in which `23skidoo` is a valid preprocessor token but not a valid token.

If your question is "should I detect and react to this error in the scanner or the parser", I would answer, "whichever seems most convenient to you". My preference is to centralize all error handling in a single place, though, which means in the parser, and that requires the scanner to pass a special "bad token" token to the parser in order to trigger error detection (and possibly recovery) in the parser.